# Cannot find QNetworkProxy in qt creator on windows

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm writing a application that needs proxy support, as I understand one can use QNetworkProxy, but whenever I type  `#include <QNetworkProxy>`it cannot find it. I've also tried the update tool to see if I missed something, but everything seems to be installed.

I run QT creator on windows7 x64, sdk version: 4.8.1.

Comment: Did you put `QT += network` into your .pro file?

Comment: Well, all I can say is Thank you! That surely did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You should add QT += network into your .pro file.